# What is advantage of parameter-less methods?

Tags: c#, mvp

MVP best practices recommend using parameter-less methods when view and presenter communicate. Even if using events, it is recommended not to use event parameters. It is recommended to change class state thru properties, which can be examined to read/write information. What is the reason for this? Does it help with testing? I am using MVP with Windows Forms, C#.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: where did you read this advice?

Comment: I can find no trace of this advice in this in-depth paper by the MVP inventor: http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf . Can you elaborate on the source and the arguments it puts forward to support this claim?

Comment: It is very difficult to find good resources about using MVP, with C# Windows Forms. E.g. search for parameterless in these web links - [link](http://thedersen.com/blog/2010/01/15/passive-view-the-way-we-do-it/) [link](https://www.drdobbs.com/tools/unit-testing-the-ui/200001974) [link](https://csharp.developreference.com/article/18594028/MVP+Pattern+with+WinForms+-+Proper+way+to+access+user+input%3F)

Comment: These links are examples of where I deduced that parameters are not recommended. I have managed to work around by using class state. But, the resulting code becomes somewhat convoluted.

Comment: Fair Warning: Winforms creates a stupidly high spike in complexity if you try to fiddle it too much to make it fit a MVP model. Be ready for bumps in the way.

Comment: @krypt: if you have some references to backup your claims, please use the **edit** button and put those references into the question, with a short **summary** of what you found there. Don't expect everyone to read all the comments here down below, and avoid to write questions which are only meaningful in context with external links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be a little bit overgeneralizing from the few examples you found on the web. However, there is indeed a correct observation:

- Views (or "Form" objects in Winforms) are very stateful objects. Most controls like text boxes, check boxes, even push buttons can have several states.
- Specificially in MVP (or similar architectures), the idea is to exclude any (business or presentation) logic from the view and place it in the presenter, so unit testing the presenter will be sufficient, and unit testing views (which is sometimes technically difficult) becomes meaningless.
- Since the view is forbidden to process any of the control's state by itself, the view's interface (lets call it `IView`) has to expose the state of all controls (naturally through properties).
- Even a simple method like

  ```
  private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
        presenter.Search(txtUserInput.Text);
  }
  ```

  can be interpreted as "logic in the view": the `btnSearch_Click` here implements passing `txtUserInput.Text` into the main `Search` logic - but this knowledge, where the "button" knows precisely which UI control holds the correct search parameter, may be seen as presentation logic which can or should be placed in the presenter. The alternative is to make the presenter's `Search` method parameterless and let it grab the search text directly through the `IView` interface.

Is this a "best practice"? IMHO this is debatable, I think this strict separation is a very puristic point of view, is has the disadvantage that the view has to expose really every kind of contrallable state through the `IView` interface, which might include the font style, color or position of a button, if this is something which can change by some program "logic".

Hence one might also decide to keep certain UI logic inside the view for making the `IView` interface smaller. Specificially the "visual" properties of the UI should probably be implemented there. However, keeping any logic out of the view has indeed the advantage of having so few logic there that unit testing the view itself is probably not necessary, and unit testing the presenter has a chance to catch errors like grabbing the search text from the wrong text box control.

Comment: Basing your design over what is easier to test makes some sense.  However, one thing I hated about TDD is that your test code, which is usually very simpleminded, ends up designing your code.  It becomes the tail wagging to dog.

Comment: @user949300: ??? TDD does not tell whether to design a `presenter.Search` method with or without parameters. Actually, not tests drive a design, the programmer who writes the tests does.

Comment: Thanks, Doc Brown. Your detailed explanation helped me understand better.